# Is it possible to show all languages on the node edit form?

Tags: nodes, forms, i18n-l10n

I am developing a drupal website with two languages. The main node type has a lot of fields, but only two are translatable.

Is it possible to show the input fields from both languages on the main edit form?

Comment: Drupal have no such way to show all the fields for all languages at once. But you can create some custom solution for it, and can achieve it feature.

Comment: @Shubham I was thinking about that but hoped there would be another solution. I think i will build my own form and then post it here.

Comment: In some previous projects I got stuck in the same situation. So, for that I generated my custom form and included all the translations along with fields for each language. But main problem will be a very lengthy form generated. Which can irritates end user to fill the form. :)